# Probability of same numbers with no repetition

Tags: probability

There is a bag that contains numbers from 1-40. A person reaches into the bag, takes a number, puts it aside and repeats this process another 3 times (has 4 numbers in total at the end). Another person comes along and gets a fresh bag of numbers, reaches and puts the 4 numbers aside. What are the chances that those two people got the same:

a) exactly 1 number

b) exactly 2 numbers

c) exactly 3 numbers

d) exactly 4 numbers

So for case a) is this valid?
1/40 * 1/40 * 40 = 2.5%

For case b and similar to others would that be:
2/40 * 2/40 * 40 = 10% ?

How would the answer differ if I said 'at least' rather than 'exactly'? E.g. at least 2 same numbers?

Thanks

Comment: Does '1 number' mean *exactly* 1 number, or *at least* 1 number?

Comment: Good point, was going to add this to the question, could you please help how the answer would differ if I said 'at least 1 number' (range) rather than 'exactly'

Comment: $P(at least 1 number) = 1 - P(no numbers)$, but with exactly one number you have to multiply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preassume that the numbers are not replaced. This on base of the fact that the second person "gets a fresh bag of numbers". That would not be necessary by replacement.

---

The probability that the second person will have *exactly* $k$ numbers that were also drawn by the first person equals:$$\frac{\binom4k\binom{36}{4-k}}{\binom{40}4}$$

It can be interpreted as: if $4$ numbers are drawn out of $40$ and $4$ of these numbers are labeled, then what is the probability that $k$ labeled numbers are drawn?

This is an application of [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

The probability that *at least* $k$ numbers are drawn that match with the numbers drawn by the first person is:$$\sum_{i=k}^4\frac{\binom4i\binom{36}{4-i}}{\binom{40}4}=1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\binom4i\binom{36}{4-i}}{\binom{40}4}$$

Handsome to choose for the side that has a minimal number of terms.

Comment: Thanks, I can work out the numbers using the example in the link. I have no idea how to work out the numbers using the second formula with range... any help? sorry only did basic level maths...

Comment: Can you find $\frac{\binom4k\binom{36}{4-k}}{\binom{40}4}$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$? Then in the second formula you must find $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1-p_0$, $p_2+p_3+p_4=1-p_0-p_1$, $p_3+p_4$  and $p_4$.